# Add distance lines to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't figure out  how to add distance lines to the chart image below without it being a manual process. the code to add the points is simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated! The lines to need to be exactly like the image either.

```
##Example data
structure(list(Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"
), Hz = c(50, 550, 1050, 800, 300, 50, 550, 1050), Vert = c(500, 
500, 550, 600, 600, 700, 750, 700)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(ex, aes(Hz,Vert,color=Type))+theme_bw()+scale_y_reverse()+
geom_segment(aes(x = 50, y = 500, xend = 50, yend = 700),color='black',size=1)+
geom_segment(aes(x = 50, y = 600, xend = 300, yend = 600),color='red',size=1)+
geom_segment(aes(x = 50, y = 500, xend = 550, yend = 500),color='orange',size=1)+
geom_segment(aes(x = 50, y = 700, xend = 1050, yend = 700),color='green',size=1)+
geom_segment(aes(x = 550, y = 700, xend = 550, yend = 750),color='black',size=1)+
geom_segment(aes(x = 550, y = 500, xend = 550, yend = 600),color='blue',size=1)+
geom_segment(aes(x = 550, y = 500, xend = 550, yend = 600),color='purple',size=1)+
geom_segment(aes(x = 300, y = 600, xend = 550, yend = 600),color='pink',size=1)+
geom_segment(aes(x = 550, y = 600, xend = 800, yend = 600),color='orange',size=1)+
geom_point(size=5)
```

[image: chart]

Comment: Could you also include the plotting code itself? That would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: no prob. I'll update question

Comment: Which is the logic of the links? How one is connect to another?

Comment: I'm just trying to convey the distance, both vertical and horizontal to the points. I plan on adding in text along the lines once I figure out how to add the lines programatically. The lines don't necessarily have to look exactly how i drew them. However the lines must not connect diagonally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this qualify:

```
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Hz, Vert, color = Type, group = 1)) +
  geom_point(size = 10) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("A" = "red", "B" = "#ffcc33", "C" = "#5b8551")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_step(color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! much appreciated. Is there a way to add the distances in text of the line segments? For example, the left red to green segment would have a distance of "200" in text.

Comment: I'll create another question for that and say this question is answered

Comment: @jsimpsno I guess it should be possible to implement a geom just like `geom_step`, but with distance labels, but I'm not that good in it.

Comment: Probably easier to just calculate the distance as a separate column or dataframe and use `geom_label`